# I try to install something using poetry I have connection error

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu, networking, proxy

I try to install numpy using poetry but I have this error when i use the home network:

```
[ConnectionError]
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/c5/63/a48648ebc57711348420670bb074998f79828291f68aebfff1642be212ec/numpy-1.19.4.zip (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f041865a250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```